# Why is my new kitchen faucet banging?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

Just had new kitchen faucet installed.  When water is turned on I get an annoying banging noise and sprayer jumps around.  Seems there is too much pressure in the sprayer - the pressure in the main sink nozzle is fine.  How can I turn down air pressure in the sprayer hose?  Even when water is off and I turn on sprayer there is a 'burst' of air.  Can this be adjusted?

Answer (score 1):

The first time you turn on the water at the faucet and/or sprayer, you'll likely find that the faucet/sprayer spits and bangs. This is normal, and is simply the air being cleared from the supply lines.

Let the water run for a bit, and you should notice the flow return to normal.

Removing the aerators, and/or other obstructions can help clear the air faster.